# How important is it to learn all of the esperanto synonyms?

Tags: word-choice

Is it necessary to learn all of the synonyms in Esperanto, like plaĝo/strando, or razeno/gazono/herbotapiŝo? sablohorloĝo/klepsidro is another one. Is there a list somewhere of which is the most commonly used in each pair?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ultimately it is up to every speaker to choose how to express themself. Naturally sticking to commonly accepted rules and words helps to getting understood.

The highest authority is [Akademio de Esperanto](https://www.akademio-de-esperanto.org), which gives recommendations of language use. The foundation is of course [*La Fundamento*](https://www.akademio-de-esperanto.org/fundamento/index.html) laid by Zamenhof himself.
A good dictionary has a marking (e.g. a star in [PIV](https://vortaro.net)) for those *fundamentaj* words.

There is also a site [*La bona lingvo*](http://bonalingvo.net/index.php/%C4%88efpa%C4%9Do), which have lists of words what they consider as preferred ones. Those lists are based on those fundamental words, their derivations and use by respected authors.

There are way too many words in Esperanto to memorise, so choose what to use. But if you choose a word that deviates from the one given in the sources above, be ready to clarify and explain.

Comment: Also, you don't need to learn them all. Right now (after 15+ years of everyday usage) I had to look up `klepsidro` (`akvohorloĝo`), although I understood `sablohorloĝo` senprobleme. Learn the official (Akademio) and Fundamental (La Fundamento) and let the others show up while interacting with others (and let them do the explaining ;)). Check the little notes by each root to know if they are official or Fundamental (there are a couple more categories). If your dictionary doesn't carry that information, it is time to use another.